# error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to compile a project on my university's ssh server and I get the error:

```
Node.h:12: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
```

Chunk of code from my Node.h class:

```
template <typename T> 

struct Node{
    T data; 
    Node *leftChild; 
    Node *rightChild; 

    Node(const T & theData = nullptr, Node *left = nullptr, Node *right = nullptr);
    Node(T && theElement = nullptr, Node *left = nullptr, Node *right = nullptr);

    T getData(); 
};
```

The server runs on `GCC` version `4.4.7` and I'm compiling using the following command:

`g++ -std=c++0x`

^ I use this command for all of my projects for this class, and this is the first time I'm running into this issue. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Your compiler is *old*.

Comment: I know, I don't know why my school hasn't updated it in so long :(

Comment: `nullptr` came into being in C++11, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Comment: @hmp54 It seems your compiler does not support the literal nullptr. Instead use NULL.

Comment: With `const T & theData = nullptr`, your elements can only be pointers (or `nullptr_t`). I doubt that it's what you want – you probably want `const T & theData = T()`

Answer (score 3):

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11, the null pointer constant is a part of GCC 4.6+. You'll have to find a way around using the nullptr constant or update the GCC version(recommended).

Comment: I can't update the GCC version since I'm working with my university's server. What's an alternative to nullptr and null? Both of them cause the same error.

Comment: @hmp54 did you try `null` or `NULL`? You could also just try `= 0` as that (I believe) is the underlying logic of `NULL`. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/